# How to add header to graph pnpjs

Tags: sharepoint-online, javascript, spfx, spfx-webparts, microsoft-graph

I tried to get all users from **Azure AD** with *Hire date* > *2012-12-31T23:59:59*.

```
return graph.users
      .select("givenName", "surname", "employeeHireDate", "id", "mail", "jobTitle")
      .filter("employeeHireDate ge 2012-12-31T23:59:59Z")
      .count
      .get()
      .then((usersList) => ....)
```

I found out that the `ConsistencyLevel` header required for advanced queries.

**ConsistencyLevel:eventual**

How can I set this Header params in my graph query?

Using: @pnp/pnpjs: ^2.0.13

Answer (score 0):

Try adding `ConsistencyLevel` header like this:

```
import { graphfi, ConsistencyLevel } from "@pnp/graph";
import "@pnp/graph/users";

const graph = graphfi().using(ConsistencyLevel());

await graph.users();
```

**Documentation**: [@pnp/graph: behaviors - ConsistencyLevel](https://pnp.github.io/pnpjs/graph/behaviors/#consistencylevel)

Comment: I tried, but have an error on setup method.
(Property 'setup' does not exist on type 'GraphFI').
`
import { graphfi, ConsistencyLevel } from "@pnp/graph";
import "@pnp/graph/users";

public onInit(): Promise<void> {
    const graph = graphfi().using(ConsistencyLevel());
    return super.onInit().then(_ => {
      graph.setup({
        spfxContext: this.context as any
      });
    });
  }
`
"@pnp/graph": "^3.13.0",

Comment: Follow this documentation and see if it helps: https://pnp.github.io/pnpjs/transition-guide/